# YouTube API v3 returns 0 subscribers for all channels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube, youtube-api

The YouTube API v3 is returning a subscriberCount value of 0 for all channel list queries when setting the param mySubscribers=true. The subscriberCount is accurate if I use the alternative "channelId" or "mine" parameters instead.

Here is a reference to the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

I'm setting the part equal to id and statistics for simplicity to get channel information. Is this a bug with the (beta) APIs?

Answer (score 0):

I has the same problem, right now for this metric you can use YouTube Data API v2, like this:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{USER-ID-OR-USERNAME}?v=2&alt=json
```

And get this metric from yt$statistics->subscriberCount

Comment: Thanks, I have been using the v2 data APIs for this value until there is a fix.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me.  Are you authenticating?  If you set mySubscribers=true and don't set mine=true (you get an error if both are set to true), you should get a list.  In that list should be a pageInfo -> totalResults, which should tell you the number.

Here is an example of a correct call from API Explorer
(https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#try-it):

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id%2Cstatistics&mySubscribers=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Authorization:  Bearer ya29.blahblah
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

Answer (score 0):

```
Get Subscribers count by following way using V3 api     
    URLString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&mySubscribers=true&access_token=%@",accessToken]    

        Response

         etag = "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/0_NpYsUUR0M4UrddABQ5GlAx0aA\"";
                items =     (
                            {
                        etag = "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/I5mDLVKzrHCsmda5ZyJOe_6dhQ0\"";
                        id = uhjUCDMMDlm9PwDGiMdfV7QeIRgasd;
                        kind = "youtube#channel";
                    },
                            {
                        etag = "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/kUNuk7bhfC8iuWaAUvnBzbv3ZdM\"";
                        id = hjvhUCdMacPC0kNs1h3O1amJ2Mdwnv;
                        kind = "youtube#channel";
                    }
                );
                kind = "youtube#channelListResponse";
                pageInfo =     {
                    resultsPerPage = 5;
                    totalResults = 3;   ////// Subscribers Count
                };
            }
```